# 'Class' is a namespace but is used like a 'type'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces

First, this is *not* the same as the many highly upvoted questions on this exact topic unless I'm missing one of them.  All of them point that the issue is I have a namespace with the same name as the class.  This is **not** the case (but it was).

I started out creating a new console application called `BatchResizer` and put a couple of classes there, but then decided to move this into a class library, called `BatchResizer.Components`; I then renamed the original console application to `BatchResizer.ConsoleRunner`, changed all classes in that project to `namespace BatchResizer.ConsoleRunner.[...]`, set the assembly name and default namespace to the same.

There is a class titled `BatchResizer` but there are no namespaces titled `[...].BatchResizer` in the project anymore, but when I do `var batchResizer = new BatchResizer()` I get the error that the namespace is used like a class.  There *are* items named like `BatchResizer.ConsoleRunner.[...]` or `BatchResizer.Components.[...]`, but nothing ending in `BatchResizer`.

I've tried "cleaning" and rebulding the project, deleting the `.suo` file, deleting the `/bin` folder of all projects in the solution, and I've went through every class in all related projects for namespace collisions.

Comment: There is a class named BatchResizer, but there are no namespaces named [...].BatchResizer

Comment: sure would make it a lot easier if you would paste the class header of all relevant code in question.. google `msdn namespace`

Comment: This is the fun part about having a class named the same as its namespace, you probably have to do `new BatchResizer.BatchResizer()`. Try to avoid having anything named the same as its parent container.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`BatchResizer` is still a namespace name, though.  If it's also the same name as a class, you'll have to be more explicit:

```
var batchResizer = new Components.BatchResizer();
```

You could also add a using statement within your namespace:

```
namespace BatchResizer.ConsoleRunner
{
    using Components;   

    internal class Program
    {        
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var batchResizer = new BatchResizer();
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to get a bit geeky, then the C# 5.0 spec has this to say:

**9.2 Namespace declarations**

> ...The qualified-identifier of a namespace-declaration may be a single identifier or a sequence of identifiers separated by “.” tokens. The latter form permits a program to define a nested namespace without lexically nesting several namespace declarations. For example,

```
namespace N1.N2
{
    class A {}
    class B {}
}
```

> is semantically equivalent to

```
namespace N1
{
    namespace N2
    {
        class A {}
        class B {}
    }
}
```

So even if, as you say, no `class` is declared in the namespace `BatchResizer`, `BatchResizer` *is* declared as a namespace.

Answer (score 1):

> First, this is not the same as the many highly upvoted questions on this exact topic unless I'm missing one of them. All of them point that the issue is I have a namespace with the same name as the class. This is not the case (but it was).

BatchResizer may not be a 'final' namespace, but it' still a namespace

```
Namespace : Foo.BatchResizer.Components
            Foo.BatchResizer.ConsoleRunner
Class :     Foo.BatchResizer
```